# Speed up typical "find" of linked list by pairing with bubble sort?

Tags: performance, linked-list, bubble-sort

I'm making a forth-like language that is supposed to run in places memory is a premium.

The language uses a linked list for it's dictionary of language words due to space constraints and lack of resizeable memory.

However, it hurts me to think of the performance costs of the linked list lookup. I understand that the worst case will always be O(n), but I was trying to think of ways to at least improve the typical case when I realized something: what if the "find" method, in addition to finding a key, also performs a single bubble-sort-like operation each time a key is hit. This way the most common keys will "bubble" to the top. Even better, the entire list will be re-weighted as compilation continues and should roughly correlate to a key's continuous statistical likelihood.

Has this technique been used in other places? I'm curious if there is a decent mathematical demonstration of it's runtime complexity (assuming a statistical curve of some names vs others). A single bubble sort operation is clearly O(1) so at least it can't hurt the theoretical runtime complexity.

Comment: you will need to maintain a hit count too, otherwise what are you sorting one. Another idea, how about storing the dictionary always sorted so you can do a binary chop lookup

Comment: It's not _exactly_ a sort in the traditional sense. It's just that each time a key is hit it will bubble up to be closer to the root node.

Storing the dictionary always sorted is interesting, but I'm not sure how I can do a binary search on a LL. I was under the impression that required O(1) index access? Do you have a link for what "binary chop" is? Note: it must be a singly-linked-list. If I'm using a doubly-linked-list I might as well use a BTree (which I may very well just do anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this strategy should improve the average run-time in common cases, this does not change the worst-case complexity which is `O(n)`.

Indeed, if the searched key is in the end of the list of size `n`, a find will run in `O(n)` time. The bubble-swap operation runs in `O(1)` time (assuming the key can actually be compared in constant time). The next find operation is a bit faster if the same key is fetched but still `O(n)`. After `n` fetches of the same key, fetching this key can be done in `O(1)` time. However, fetching `n` other key in a specific order can reorder the list so that the initial key is put at the end. More specifically, fetching the item next to the initial key `n` times does that. In the end, fetching `n` time the initial key and `n` other keys in a specific order results in `(n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2 + 1) + (1 + 2 + ... + n-1 + n) = n*(n-1) = n²-n = O(n²)` operations. After these operations, the list should be in the same state then the initial one. Thus, the complexity is clearly `O(n)`.

Note that you can implement a cache to speed up fetches. Many policies exists. You can find some of them described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies). Note that this should not impact the complexity, but will certainly greatly improve the execution time. The cache can store an iterator to a node of the linked list. Iterators are not invalidated when items are inserted/deleted (unless the target item is actually deleted).

Note also that linked lists are generally very slow. They are not very efficient in term of memory usage too because the pointer to the next item take some space (8 bytes on a 64-bit architecture). Allocated nodes can also require some hidden space regarding the standard library allocator used (some store pointer metadata like the allocated space). A solution to use less memory is to use linked list containing buckets of key-value pairs.

Note that while *balanced binary search trees* require a bit more memory, they can be much more efficient to solve this problem. The complexity of finding a key in such data structure is `O(log n)`. A good hash-map implementation can be quite compact in memory (see [hopscotch hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopscotch_hashing)) too although the memory consumption of the hash-map can be quite big when it is resized.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough overview, really appreciate the answer. I'm not really sure I believe your proof: for example if 90% of the find calls were for 10% of the keys, then this should make 90% of the calls run in 1/10 the time, so I would think the time would be something like O(P n) where P is a function related to the probability distribution. However, I suppose all that would ever do is give a constant improvement, which is just reduced to O(n)... :(

Comment: I had considered caching as well, and that may be a solution. The other option is to map it as a hashmap when lots of lookups are needed and then drop the hashmap. I'll have to consider all the tradeoffs, thanks!

Comment: Note that in the answer I specifically talked about the *worst-case complexity*. Not the best case nor the average run-time. This specific case is very unlikely to occur just by chance on *random* operations. The probability is something 1/n!. Still, complexity matters because programs generally does not behave randomly. A good similar situation is quick-sort: it is fast in *average* (`O(n log n)`), but very slow in the *worst-case* (`O(n * n)`). Worst case are just a very tiny faction of cases but it happens in practice besides being randomly unlikely to happen.

Comment: For the average time and programs accessing to all keys uniformly, it can be shown that the runtime is `O(n)` too. Indeed, for each key at the location `k`, the probability to move it toward the beginning of the list is `0.5` because it is `P(s > k)` where `s` is the index of the selected (uniformly chosen random) key. This means that for many runs the indices behaves like a normal distribution centered on their initial position (due to the Bernoulli law). Hopefully, most programs does not behave uniformly randomly. They more probably behave following a Pareto distribution.

Comment: Right, but even for a more favorable distribution the speedup factor would not be dependent on the size of the inputs, so would be excluded from the theoretical runtime, right? All except toy examples such as where only F functions (I e. 10) are basically ever accessed, which would make it O(F). But in that case caching would work just as well.